# OnLoadFinished called infinitely

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, loader

Yesterday I try to write my content provider and to test it. Unfortunately, this piece of code:

```
if(loader.getId() == 1)       
 getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.example.djak.contentprovidertest.provider/cte"), values);
```

does something, because of which onLoadFinished is called infinitely. Has someone idea what is going on? When I remove it onLoadFinished is called only once.
And when onLoaderReset is called ? Can someone give me an real example to test it?
Thanks in advance.

Thas is the all code for the loader:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    loader = new CursorLoader(this, Uri.parse("content://com.example.djak.contentprovidertest.provider/cte"),
            null, null, null, null);


    Log.d("Some looong data", "Create");

    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("user", "s");


    if(loader.getId() == 1) getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.example.djak.contentprovidertest.provider/cte"), values);

    Log.d("Some looong data", "Finish");


}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "RESET", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And I set onClickListener of one of my buttons:

```
       findViewById(R.id.temp_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, MainActivity.this);
       }
   });
```

I just try that and I don't know why onLoadFinished is called infinitely times.

Comment: incomplete code will not help you

Comment: Ok, I add the all code for the loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader%3CD%3E,%20D))

> **The Loader will monitor for changes to the data, and report them to**
>   **you through new calls here. (here = onLoadFinished method)**  You should not monitor the data yourself.
>   For example, if the data is a Cursor and you place it in a
>   CursorAdapter, use the CursorAdapter(android.content.Context,
>   android.database.Cursor, int) constructor without passing in either
>   FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY or FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER (that is, use 0
>   for the flags argument). This prevents the CursorAdapter from doing
>   its own observing of the Cursor, which is not needed since when a
>   change happens you will get a new Cursor throw another call here.

That being said, when you are calling

```
if(loader.getId() == 1) getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://com.example.djak.contentprovidertest.provider/cte"), values);
```

Inside the `onLoadFinished`, you are triggering the `onLoadFinished` method again, creating an indefinite loop.

Comment: Thank you very much !  This explains what happens! And when onLoaderReset is called in practical situation ? 
Actually I was interested in loaders, because somewhere before I read that they can manage rotating the screen situation when you have background thread(which is inconvinient with Async task) i.e. the loader  will not change view on the old activity, but can you explain me how that can be achieve ? I know that Async task can cause memory leak or change of view which doesn't exist any more, but how this can be fied by loaders ???

Comment: @DPM that's very good questions, and explaining it will take some time and effort. I'd suggest that you open up new questions to adress this. Good luck and happy coding :-)